# Terminating SSH session executed by bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a script I can run locally to remotely start a server:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@host.com <<EOF
  nohup /path/to/run.sh &
EOF
echo 'done'
```

After running nohup, it hangs. I have to hit ctrl-c to exit the script.

I've tried adding an explicit exit at the end of the here doc and using "-t" argument for ssh. Neither works. How do I make this script exit immediately?

EDIT: The client is OSX 10.6, server is Ubuntu.

Comment: What SSH client are you using?  The -t option should work unless the client is doing something weird.

Comment: Oops should have mentioned this is on OSX, standard ssh client. Updated the question.

Comment: What's the meaning of EOF?

Comment: @GreenLei "End Of File" but this is a Heredoc so any other word could have been used, e.g. END. As long as it's the same in both places.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem is that nohup can't redirect output when you come in from ssh, it only redirects to nohup.out when it thinks it's connected to a terminal, and I the stdin override you have will prevent that, even with `-t`.

A workaround might be to redirect the output yourself, then the ssh client can disconnect - it's not waiting for the stream to close.  Something like:

```
nohup /path/to/run.sh > run.log &
```

*(This worked for me in a simple test connecting to an Ubuntu server from an OS X client.)*

Comment: That worked great, thanks. I actually had tried redirecting INPUT from /dev/null, but didn't think of trying with output! (I've tested this does work fine redirecting to /dev/null too, ie  nohup /path/to/run.sh > /dev/null & )

Comment: I am having a similar issue to the OP.  I am ssh-ing from a `csh` script, running commands on a remote, and attempting to send the output back to a variable in the `csh` script. Do you think this is possible? I am having the same error: I am doing `ssh -t -t` and getting the error: `Inappropriate IOCtl for device`

Answer (score 8):

The problem might be that ...

```
... ssh is respecting the POSIX standard when not closing the session 
if a process is still attached to the tty.
```

Therefore a solution might be to detach the `stdin` of the `nohup` command from the tty:

```
nohup /path/to/run.sh </dev/null &
```

See: [SSH Hangs On Exit When Using nohup](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/ssh-hangs-on-exit-when-using-nohup.html)

Yet another approach might be to use `ssh -t -t` to force pseudo-tty allocation even if `stdin` isn't a terminal.

```
man ssh | less -Ip 'multiple -t'

ssh -t -t user@host.com <<EOF
  nohup /path/to/run.sh &
EOF
```

See: [BASH spawn subshell for SSH and continue with program flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185717/bash-spawn-subshell-for-ssh-and-continue-with-program-flow)

Comment: Thanks.

The first one didn't work, same result as before.

-t -t *did* work (-t -t), but gave the error "tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device", which makes sense in light of what the double -t does. I searched around for a way to remove the error (I'd rather do this as cleanly as possible) and couldn't see how to do it with a heredoc. Turns out Martin Clayton's answer solves this, so I left it there.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting the stdin of the remote host from a here document while invoking `ssh` without an explicit command leads to the message: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

To avoid this message either use `ssh`'s `-T` switch to tell the remote host there is no need to allocate a pseudo-terminal or explicitly specify a command (such as `/bin/sh`) for the remote host to execute the commands provided by the here document.

If an explicit command is given to `ssh`, the default is to provide **no** login shell in the form of a pseudo-terminal, i. e. there will be no normal login session when a command is specified (see `man ssh`).

Without a command specified for `ssh`, on the other hand, the default is to create a pseudo-tty for an interactive login session on the remote host.

```
- ssh user@host.com <<EOF
+ ssh -T user@host.com <<EOF
+ ssh user@host.com /bin/bash <<EOF
```

As a rule, `ssh -t` or even `ssh -t -t` should only be used if there are commands that expect stdin / stdout to be a terminal (such as `top` or `vim`) or if it is necessary to kill the remote shell and its children when the `ssh` client command finishes execution (see: [ssh command unexpectedly continues on other system after ssh terminates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39605)).

As far as I can tell, the only way to combine an `ssh` command that does not allocate a pseudo-tty and a `nohup` command that writes to `nohup.out` on the remote host is to let the `nohup` command execute in a pseudo-terminal **not** created by the `ssh` mechanism. This can be done with the `script` command, for example, and will avoid the `tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device` message.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh localhost /bin/sh <<EOF
  #0<&-  script -q /dev/null nohup sleep 10 1>&- &
  #0<&- script -q -c "nohup sh -c 'date; sleep 10 1>&- &'" /dev/null  # Linux
  0<&- script -q /dev/null nohup sh -c 'date; sleep 10 1>&- &'        # FreeBSD, Mac OS X
  cat nohup.out
  exit 0
EOF
echo 'done'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `exit 0` at the end.