# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to write a shell script that creates some directories on a remote server and then uses scp to copy files from my local machine onto the remote. Here's what I have so far:

```
ssh -t user@server<<EOT
DEP_ROOT='/home/matthewr/releases'
datestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
REL_DIR=$DEP_ROOT"/"$datestamp
if [ ! -d "$DEP_ROOT" ]; then
    echo "creating the root directory"
    mkdir $DEP_ROOT
fi
mkdir $REL_DIR
exit
EOT

scp ./dir1 user@server:$REL_DIR
scp ./dir2 user@server:$REL_DIR
```

Whenever I run it I get this message:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

And the script just hangs forever.

My public key is trusted on the server and I can run all the commands outside of the script just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You can simply specify the terminal to use like `ssh user@server /bin/bash <<EOT…`

Comment: @Buzut: You probably mean _shell_, but, yes, specifying `/bin/bash` explicitly is one way to avoid the problem.

Comment: @mklement0 indeed, that's what I meant. Thx for correcting that ;)

Comment: In case anyone has the same problem I have, it seems that running `ssh` from `subprocess.run("ssh ....")` in `python` is different when it is running under `pytest`. The later does something funny with `stdin` while the former doesn't.  So your code works, but the tests fail.  Adding `-tt` to the command line fixed it.

Answer (score 663, accepted):

Try `ssh -t -t`(or `ssh -tt` for short) to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin isn't a terminal.

See also: [Terminating SSH session executed by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085429/terminating-ssh-session-executed-by-bash-script)

From ssh manpage:

```
-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.

-t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary 
        screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
        e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty
        allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: As you can see above, I was already trying -t. I will look at redirecting the output though.

Comment: This suggestion fixed my problem. I have a script calling another one in the background: "source myscript.sh &" . Inside "myscript.sh" there is ssh that is using "sudo" like this: ssh user@host "sudo <command>". Using a single -t parameter didn't help, only "-t -t".

Comment: I am having a similar issue in a script that is run here.  I added the -t -t but now I am getting a new error.

"tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Comment: Brilliant!  Who would have guessed at using multiple -t options!  I was trying to ssh from a Windows EC2 image I had remoted into and was getting no where.  Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean when it says "even if ssh has no local tty"?

Comment: Since the OP's commands do not involve interaction with a terminal, there is no need to use a pty (pseudo-terminal), use of which has potentially unwanted side effects, notably reporting both stdout and stderr via stdout to the calling shell.
Thus, `-T` is the right solution here, given the OP's approach. Generally, however, for "batch" use, the commands should be passed as a _command-line argument_ rather than via _stdin_, which avoids the whole pty problem altogether.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: If you provide commands to `ssh` via _stdin_, its stdin, due to the input redirection, is no longer connected to a _terminal_, so in that sense "ssh has no local tty" anymore. It is in this scenario that a _single_ `-t` is insufficient to allocate a pty and `-t -t` (`-tt`) must be used instead. That said, you can avoid all this if you don't provide commands via _stdin_ to begin with, and use a command-line _argument_ instead.

Comment: So `-t` and `-t -t` all about allocating a pty on the remote side of the connection. And the problem is that local side stdin is not a pty, so you can either fully disable it with `-T`, or force a remote side pty. The choice depends on whether the commands you are running on remote side relies on there being a tty or not. But it is puzzling as to why ssh is hanging as is claimed by the question.

Comment: The question `Inappropriate IOCtl for device` is answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1605195/2969544)**

Answer (score 258):

Also with option `-T` from [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh#T)

> Disable pseudo-tty allocation

Comment: This answer needs more points - its the right answer, and not too long like the answer by zanco, its absurd that "oh allocate a TTY anyway with -t -t" gets 107 points, when you can just skip it altogether

Comment: Just upvoted; it did worked better for me than -t -t

Comment: '-t -t' works, however with '-T' i get 'sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo'

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: @nhed: The `-tt` option appears best for those of us that actually want a TTY and are getting the OP's error message. This `-T` answer is better if you don't need the TTY.

Comment: @ErichBSchulz well, I'm well aware about `-tt` but from my cursory look the OP's script I don't see why he would need a TTY

Comment: @nhed - sure - but i'm sure others like me got here from Googling the error in the error message. It seems not unreasonable to make clear how other googlers should choose between 2 competing answers. or maybe not. i dont know

Comment: `-T` option fixed `Inappropriate ioctl for device` generated by `-t -t` **for me**

Comment: The answer is - *it depends*. If you need a TTY (like to run an interactive shell), then use `-tt`, if you don't need a TTY (like when running a script), then use `-T`. Most people do need a shell, so they need `-tt`.

Answer (score 120):

Per [zanco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21757258), you're not providing a remote command to `ssh`, given how the shell parses the command line.  To solve this problem, change the syntax of your `ssh` command invocation so that the remote command is comprised of a syntactically correct, multi-line string.

There are a variety of syntaxes that can be used.  For example, since commands can be piped into `bash` and `sh`, and probably other shells too, the simplest solution is to just combine `ssh` shell invocation with heredocs:

```
ssh user@server /bin/bash <<'EOT'
echo "These commands will be run on: $( uname -a )"
echo "They are executed by: $( whoami )"
EOT
```

Note that executing the above *without* `/bin/bash` will result in the warning `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`.  Also note that `EOT` is surrounded by single-quotes, so that `bash` recognizes the heredoc as a *nowdoc*, turning off local variable interpolation so that the command text will be passed as-is to `ssh`.

If you are a fan of pipes, you can rewrite the above as follows:

```
cat <<'EOT' | ssh user@server /bin/bash
echo "These commands will be run on: $( uname -a )"
echo "They are executed by: $( whoami )"
EOT
```

The same caveat about `/bin/bash` applies to the above.

Another valid approach is to pass the multi-line remote command as a single string, using multiple layers of `bash` variable interpolation as follows:

```
ssh user@server "$( cat <<'EOT'
echo "These commands will be run on: $( uname -a )"
echo "They are executed by: $( whoami )"
EOT
)"
```

The solution above fixes this problem in the following manner:

1. `ssh user@server` is parsed by bash, and is interpreted to be the `ssh` command, followed by an argument `user@server` to be passed to the `ssh` command
2. `"` begins an interpolated string, which when completed, will comprise an argument to be passed to the `ssh` command, which in this case will be interpreted by `ssh` to be the remote command to execute as `user@server`
3. `$(` begins a command to be executed, with the output being captured by the surrounding interpolated string
4. `cat` is a command to output the contents of whatever file follows.  The output of `cat` will be passed back into the capturing interpolated string
5. `<<` begins a bash *heredoc*
6. `'EOT'` specifies that the name of the heredoc is EOT.  The single quotes `'` surrounding EOT specifies that the heredoc should be parsed as a *nowdoc*, which is a special form of heredoc in which the contents do not get interpolated by bash, but rather passed on in literal format
7. Any content that is encountered between `<<'EOT'` and `<newline>EOT<newline>` will be appended to the nowdoc output
8. `EOT` terminates the nowdoc, resulting in a nowdoc temporary file being created and passed back to the calling `cat` command. `cat` outputs the nowdoc and passes the output back to the capturing interpolated string
9. `)` concludes the command to be executed
10. `"` concludes the capturing interpolated string.  The contents of the interpolated string will be passed back to `ssh` as a single command line argument, which `ssh` will interpret as the remote command to execute as `user@server`

If you need to avoid using external tools like `cat`, and don't mind having two statements instead of one, use the `read` built-in with a heredoc to generate the SSH command:

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' SSH_COMMAND <<'EOT'
echo "These commands will be run on: $( uname -a )"
echo "They are executed by: $( whoami )"
EOT

ssh user@server "${SSH_COMMAND}"
```

Comment: +1 one and a half years later! :) really clear explanation. well done

Comment: For me (and I'm by no means a "DevOps" person) this is what worked (I'm using Jenkins).  I also tried the "-t -t" and "-T" suggestions, but ran into open stream issues and non-execution issues.

Comment: 2 years later, really helpfull

Comment: +1 Awesome explanation. But if you make the last code snippet (IFS='' *) an function for executing remote commands, how would you pass $1 into the IFS='' *? It docent seem to recognize the content of $1 at all.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk maybe you can demonstrate an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Nice writeup. The `"$(cat <<'EOT'…` approach is a bit heavy-handed, given that you can simply use a multi-line `'…'` string directly, as in [Henning's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7115046/45375). I suggest avoiding the term _nowdoc_, because it is not customary in the world of POSIX-like shells (the term comes from PHP).

Comment: @mklement0 What if your multi-line string has single-quotes? That entire solution then breaks.

Comment: @DejayClayton: Then the `read -d '' -r var <<'EOF' ...` here-doc approach, as in your second command (which I hadn't previously noticed - sorry), is preferable. Alternatively, you can use a multi-line `"..."` string and `\ `-escape `$` instances as needed, or even splice `'\''` sequences into `'...'` multi-line strings.

Comment: @mklement0 Sure, you can escape strings as needed, but who wants the hassle of having to modify script statements that you might just be copying and pasting from another shell script, or stackoverflow for that matter?  Also, the elegance of `cat` solution is that it is accomplished in a single (albeit compound) statement, and doesn't result in temporary variables polluting the shell environment.

Comment: Yes, for the scenario of copying existing shell code while also avoiding the use of an auxiliary shell variable, the `"$(cat <<'EOT'...` approach is a good choice.

Comment: Nice, well written and clear!

Answer (score 67):

I'm adding this answer because it solved a related problem that I was having with the same error message.

**Problem**: I had installed cygwin under Windows and was getting this error: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`

**Resolution**: It turns out that I had **not** installed the openssh client program and utilities.  Because of that cygwin was using the Windows implementation of ssh, not the cygwin version.  The solution was to install the openssh cygwin package.

Comment: For me it turned out it was another ssh implementiation in the PATH: `$ which ssh/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/ssh`

Comment: and to install `openssh` this may be the way to go for Windows: https://superuser.com/a/301026/260710

Comment: This solution works for me. After installing openssh, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 56):

All relevant information is in the existing answers, but let me attempt a **pragmatic summary**:

**tl;dr:**

- **DO pass the commands to run using a *command-line argument***:
  `ssh jdoe@server '...'`

  - **`'...'` strings can span multiple lines**, so you can keep your code readable even without the use of a here-document:
    `ssh jdoe@server ' ... '`
- **Do NOT pass the commands via *stdin***, as is the case when you use a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):
  `ssh jdoe@server <<'EOF' # Do NOT do this ... EOF`

**Passing the commands *as an argument* works as-is**, and:

- **the problem with the pseudo-terminal will not even arise.**
- **you won't need an `exit` statement** at the end of your commands, because the session will automatically exit after the commands have been processed.

In short: passing commands via *stdin* is a mechanism that is at odds with `ssh`'s design and causes problems that must then be worked around.
Read on, if you want to know more.

---

#### Optional background information:

**`ssh`'s mechanism for accepting commands to execute on the target server is a *command-line argument***: the final operand (non-option argument) accepts a string containing one or more shell commands.

- By default, these **commands run unattended, in a *non-interactive* shell, without the use of a (pseudo) terminal (option `-T` is implied), and the session automatically ends** when the last command finishes processing.
- In the event that your commands require *user interaction*, such as responding to an interactive prompt, you can explicitly request the creation of a [pty (pseudo-tty)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal), a pseudo terminal, that enables interacting with the remote session, using the `-t` option; e.g.:

  - `ssh -t jdoe@server 'read -p "Enter something: "; echo "Entered: [$REPLY]"'`
  - Note that the interactive `read` prompt only works correctly with a pty, so the `-t` option is needed.
  - Using a pty has a notable side effect: stdout and stderr are *combined* and both reported via *stdout*; in other words: you lose the distinction between regular and error output; e.g.:

    - `ssh jdoe@server 'echo out; echo err >&2'      # OK - stdout and stderr separate`
    - `ssh -t jdoe@server 'echo out; echo err >&2'   # !! stdout + stderr -> stdout`

**In the absence of this argument, `ssh` creates an *interactive* shell** - including when you send commands via *stdin*, which is where the trouble begins:

- For an *interactive* shell, `ssh` normally allocates a pty (pseudo-terminal) by default, *except* if its stdin is not connected to a (real) terminal.

  - **Sending commands via stdin means that `ssh`'s stdin is no longer connected to a terminal, so *no* pty is created, and `ssh` *warns* you accordingly**:
    `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`
  - **Even the `-t` option, whose express purpose is to *request* creation of a pty, is *not* enough *in this case***: you'll get the same warning.

    - Somewhat curiously, you must then ***double* the `-t` option** to force creation of a pty: `ssh -t -t ...` or `ssh -tt ...` shows that you *really, really mean it*.
    - Perhaps the rationale for requiring this very deliberate step is that *things may not work as expected*. For instance, on macOS 10.12, the apparent equivalent of the above command, providing the commands via stdin and using `-tt`, does *not* work properly; the session gets stuck after responding to the `read` prompt:
      `ssh -tt jdoe@server <<<'read -p "Enter something: "; echo "Entered: [$REPLY]"'`

---

In the unlikely event that the commands you want to pass as an argument make the command line too long for your system (if its length approaches `getconf ARG_MAX` - see [this article](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/)), consider copying the code to the remote system in the form of a script first (using, e.g., `scp`), and then send a command to execute that script.

In a pinch, use `-T`, and provide the commands via *stdin*, with a trailing `exit` command, but note that if you also need interactive features, using `-tt` in lieu of `-T` may not work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, the -tt way was making the terminal display every command sent through ssh.

Comment: "double the -t option to force creation of a pty: ssh -t -t ... or ssh -tt ... shows that you really, really mean it." - ha, ha - thanks it funny but serious too - I can't get my head around the double t all I know is if I put in a single t it doesn't wrok

Comment: And I was having trouble getting a process to abort that I started remotely when it was started by redirecting commands to stdin but creating the commands as a multi line string and then passing that value as the last argument to ssh got the normal/expected behavior back. Thanks for the advice and the clarifications.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me very usefull and informative thanks a lot.

Answer (score 43):

The warning message `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` is due to the fact that no command is specified for `ssh` while stdin is redirected from a here document. 
Due to the lack of a specified command as an argument `ssh` first expects an interactive login session (which would require the allocation of a pty on the remote host) but then has to realize that its local stdin is no tty/pty. Redirecting `ssh`'s stdin from a here document normally requires a command (such as `/bin/sh`) to be specified as an argument to `ssh` - and in such a case no pty will be allocated on the remote host by default.

Since there are no commands to be executed via `ssh` that require the presence of a tty/pty (such as `vim` or `top`) the `-t` switch to `ssh` is superfluous.
Just use `ssh -T user@server <<EOT ...` or `ssh user@server /bin/bash <<EOT ...` and the warning will go away.

If `<<EOF` is not escaped or single-quoted (i. e. `<<\EOT` or `<<'EOT'`) variables inside the here document will be expanded by the local shell before it is executing `ssh ...`. The effect is that the variables inside the here document will remain empty because they are defined only in the remote shell.

So, if `$REL_DIR` should be both accessible by the local shell and defined in the remote shell, `$REL_DIR` has to be defined outside the here document before the `ssh` command (**version 1** below); or, if `<<\EOT` or `<<'EOT'` is used, the output of the `ssh` command can be assigned to `REL_DIR` if the only output of the `ssh` command to stdout is genererated by `echo "$REL_DIR"` inside the escaped/single-quoted here document (**version 2** below).

A third option would be to store the here document in a variable and then pass this variable as a command argument to `ssh -t user@server "$heredoc"` (**version 3** below).

And, last but not least, it would be no bad idea to check if the directories on the remote host were created successfully (see: [check if file exists on remote host with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845206/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-host-with-ssh/)).

```
# version 1

unset DEP_ROOT REL_DIR
DEP_ROOT='/tmp'
datestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
REL_DIR="${DEP_ROOT}/${datestamp}"

ssh localhost /bin/bash <<EOF
if [ ! -d "$DEP_ROOT" ] && [ ! -e "$DEP_ROOT" ]; then
   echo "creating the root directory" 1>&2
   mkdir "$DEP_ROOT"
fi
mkdir "$REL_DIR"
#echo "$REL_DIR"
exit
EOF

scp -r ./dir1 user@server:"$REL_DIR"
scp -r ./dir2 user@server:"$REL_DIR"


# version 2

REL_DIR="$(
ssh localhost /bin/bash <<\EOF
DEP_ROOT='/tmp'
datestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
REL_DIR="${DEP_ROOT}/${datestamp}"
if [ ! -d "$DEP_ROOT" ] && [ ! -e "$DEP_ROOT" ]; then
   echo "creating the root directory" 1>&2
   mkdir "$DEP_ROOT"
fi
mkdir "$REL_DIR"
echo "$REL_DIR"
exit
EOF
)"

scp -r ./dir1 user@server:"$REL_DIR"
scp -r ./dir2 user@server:"$REL_DIR"


# version 3

heredoc="$(cat <<'EOF'
# -onlcr: prevent the terminal from converting bare line feeds to carriage return/line feed pairs
stty -echo -onlcr
DEP_ROOT='/tmp'
datestamp="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
REL_DIR="${DEP_ROOT}/${datestamp}"
if [ ! -d "$DEP_ROOT" ] && [ ! -e "$DEP_ROOT" ]; then
   echo "creating the root directory" 1>&2
   mkdir "$DEP_ROOT"
fi
mkdir "$REL_DIR"
echo "$REL_DIR"
stty echo onlcr
exit
EOF
)"

REL_DIR="$(ssh -t localhost "$heredoc")"

scp -r ./dir1 user@server:"$REL_DIR"
scp -r ./dir2 user@server:"$REL_DIR"
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation on what this error means and why it is appearing when using a heredoc, this helped me to actually understand it rather than just work around it.

Comment: *This* is the best answer, explaining thing well and shortly.

Answer (score 26):

I don't know where the hang comes from, but redirecting (or piping) commands into an interactive ssh is in general a recipe for problems. It is more robust to use the command-to-run-as-a-last-argument style and pass the script on the ssh command line:

```
ssh user@server 'DEP_ROOT="/home/matthewr/releases"
datestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
REL_DIR=$DEP_ROOT"/"$datestamp
if [ ! -d "$DEP_ROOT" ]; then
    echo "creating the root directory"
    mkdir $DEP_ROOT
fi
mkdir $REL_DIR'
```

(All in one giant `'`-delimited multiline command-line argument).

The pseudo-terminal message is because of your `-t` which asks ssh to try to make the environment it runs on the remote machine look like an actual terminal to the programs that run there. Your ssh client is refusing to do that because its *own* standard input is not a terminal, so it has no way to pass the special terminal APIs onwards from the remote machine to your actual terminal at the local end.

What were you trying to achieve with `-t` anyway?

Comment: The -t option was an attempt to fix the Psuedo terminal problem (it didn't work). I tried your solution, it got rid of the psuedo terminal thing but now it just hangs...

Comment: @Henning: Can you please elaborate or provide a link regarding the disadvantages of redirecting or piping into an interactive ssh?

Comment: a bit late but: here you do not need a pseudo terminal, so use option `-T` instead.

Comment: ...but if the command you are sending _needs_ quotes and double quotes, your best option is a heredoc.

Answer (score 7):

After reading a lot of these answers I thought I would share my resulting solution. All I added is `/bin/bash` before the heredoc and it doesn't give the error anymore.

Use this:

```
ssh user@machine /bin/bash <<'ENDSSH'
   hostname
ENDSSH
```

Instead of this (gives error):

```
ssh user@machine <<'ENDSSH'
   hostname
ENDSSH
```

Or use this:

```
ssh user@machine /bin/bash < run-command.sh
```

Instead of this (gives error):

```
ssh user@machine < run-command.sh
```

**EXTRA**:

If you still want a remote interactive prompt e.g. if the script you're running remotely prompts you for a password or other information, because the previous solutions won't allow you to type into the prompts.

```
ssh -t user@machine "$(<run-command.sh)"
```

And if you also want to log the entire session in a file `logfile.log`:

```
ssh -t user@machine "$(<run-command.sh)" | tee -a logfile.log
```

Comment: Out of everything here. `ssh -t user@machine "$(<run-command.sh)"` is the only one that does the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error under Windows using emacs 24.5.1 to connect to some company servers through /ssh:user@host. What solved my problem was setting the "tramp-default-method" variable to "plink" and whenever I connect to a server I ommit the ssh protocol. You need to have PuTTY's plink.exe installed for this to work.

**Solution**

1. M-x customize-variable (and then hit Enter)
2. tramp-default-method (and then hit Enter again)
3. On the text field put plink and then Apply and Save the buffer
4. Whenever I try to access a remote server I now use C-x-f /user@host: and then input the password. The connection is now correctly made under Emacs on Windows to my remote server.