# python - running ssh/rsync commands in a script called via crontab

Tags: python, ssh, rsync, fabric

I have a very strange issue that I can't seem to figure out.

When I execute a python script containing the following lines while inside a SSH terminal (putty), it works fine. But the moment I run the script via crontab or even `nohup python myscript >/dev/null 2>&1&` it doesn't seem to execute these commands.

```
subprocess.call('rsync -avr /path/to/folder/. --include "delta.*" --exclude "*" -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path/to/key.pem" ec2-user@'+server+':/path/to/folder/', shell=True)
local('ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path/to/key.pem ec2-user@'+server+' "sudo /usr/bin/indexer -c /path/to/sphinx.conf --merge main delta --rotate"')
```

Basically all the above is doing is syncing a folder with new sphinx search engine updates to a remote server, then the second line runs a remote ssh command to force the search engine to rotate updates into production.

I do have fabric installed (hence the local command) but to avoid having to fab a second file I was hoping a single line of code could allow me to execute sudo commands on a remote server.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, for ssh commands in a script run in the background, you need to to have `-t -t` to force a pseudo terminal.

Reference:

[Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal)