# Qt QProcess read ssh verbose output

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qtcore, qprocess

I managed to read ssh verbose mode output with QProcess. But, like in the terminal, if ssh is successfully logged in, it will stop the process. But, in the terminal, I can see the verbose output if there are connections using ssh.
I make ssh for dynamic forwarding like this command:

```
ssh -vfCND31338 -l username -p 22 myhost
```

the problem is that QProcess will stop reading output when ssh successfully logged in. for the rest verbose, it doesn't read anymore. What should I do with this?

Comment: You mean you want to capture all the commands after the login?

Comment: Yes, to make sure when it is disconnected, because it's disconnected at any time

Comment: You could check if the process is still running with an interval?

Comment: I will use `ps aux | grep ssh` with a new QProcess to do that, but I prefer to read the `Write error: broken pipe` from the ssh verbose output.

Comment: pgrep is even better :-)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion using `pgrep` :)

Comment: See this post, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743793/how-to-detect-when-ssh-connection-over-a-qprocess-has-finished It is somewhat relevant. In an ideal world, you would use an ssh library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible off-hand with stock Qt, but e.g. you could poll with a certain interval if the ssh session is still running. In that case, `pgrep` is your friend.