# How can I get grunt to run a remote command that prompts for a sudo password?

Tags: ssh, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I'm using grunt, and I need it to execute a script on a remote machine that requires sudo access, and therefore prompts for a password.

I want it to prompt for the password, because I don't want to have to commit the password to source control.

From the command line the following is working correctly:

```
ssh -t examplehost.com "sudo ls"
```

However when I run the same command via [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) I get the following:

```
$ grunt exec:remote_sudo
Running "exec:remote_sudo" (exec) task
>> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>> Sorry, try again.
>> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>> Sorry, try again.
>> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>> Sorry, try again.
>> sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
>> Exited with code: 1.
Warning: Task "exec:remote_sudo" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The [answer to this question with a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal) suggests adding an additional `-t` switch to force the pseudo-terminal tty allocation.

Doing so gets the password prompt to show, but something isn't right, as it shows my password in the clear as I type it (the usual behaviour shows no output as you type), and it hangs forever:

```
$ grunt exec:remote_sudo
Running "exec:remote_sudo" (exec) task
[sudo] password for tom: not_my_password
# hangs forever here
```

What do I need to change to get grunt to run this script? I'm open to alternatives to `grunt-exec`, but I want to stick with grunt if at all possible.

---

Example `Gruntfile.js` for reference:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    exec: {
      remote_sudo: 'ssh -t examplehost.com "sudo ls"',
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to pipe the password to the command, as seen in this [grunt-ssh ticket](https://github.com/chuckmo/grunt-ssh/issues/42).

`echo password | sudo -S ls`

You could pass the password to the task as an argument; something like `grunt ssh_task:myPasswordHere`. Here's a totally untested Gruntfile that might work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    exec: {
      remote_sudo: {
        cmd: function(password) {
          return 'echo ' + password + ' | ssh -t examplehost.com "sudo ls"';
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

  grunt.registerTask('ssh_task', 'run remote command', function(password) {
    grunt.task.run(['exec:remote_sudo:' + password]);
  });
};
```

The downside here is that the password is still visible while you're typing it and would be in your shell history.