# CI with Gitlab and Digital Ocean

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have my website hosted on Digital Ocean and my repo on gitlab.  I do not have an instance of gitlab installed on my Digital Ocean Server.  I am just using the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

In my CI script, I ssh into digital ocean, CD into my project and attempt to pull the latest code.

I have also generated an ssh key on the digital ocean server and added it to my ssh-keys on Gitlab.

I'm not sure if there is a firewall that I can't get past or something.

unfortunately, it errors out with this error.

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.9.0 (82714ae)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.1 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.1 ...
Running on runner-4e4528ca-project-1209495-concurrent-0 via runner-        4e4528ca-machine-1484021348-29523945-digital-ocean-4gb...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/Rchampin/ryan_the_developer_django'...
Checking out b3783fbf as master...
$ ssh root@myIP
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Host key verification failed.

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Here is my CI script.

```
before_script:
  - ssh root@myIP
  - cd /home/rchampin/ryan_the_developer_django

pull:
  script:
    - git pull
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have some optinos to try in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7114990/6309)

```
ssh -t -t
# or
ssh -T
```

That should avoid requesting a pseudo terminal.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877