# How to set AND expand variables in a heredoc section

Tags: bash, sh, heredoc

I have a heredoc that needs to call existing variables from the main script, *and* set its own variables to use later. Something like this:

```
count=0

ssh $other_host <<ENDSSH
  if [[ "${count}" == "0" ]]; then
    output="string1"
  else
    output="string2"
  fi
  echo output
ENDSSH
```

That doesn't work because 'output' doesn't get set to anything.

I tried using the solution from this question:

```
count=0

ssh $other_host << \ENDSSH
  if [[ "${count}" == "0" ]]; then
    output="string1"
  else
    output="string2"
  fi
  echo output
ENDSSH
```

It didn't work either. $output got set to "string2" because $count wasn't expanded.

How can I use a heredoc that expands variables from the parent script, *and* sets its own variables?

Comment: It is behaving as expected. The code inside the heredoc runs on a remote host and it doesn't see the `count=0` initialization.

Comment: Is there some way to pass the variable (and a couple of others) into the heredoc execution?

Comment: There is no "heredoc execution".  The heredoc defines a string.  The string is passed to ssh, where it is evaluated by the shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
count=0

ssh -t -t "$other_host" << ENDSSH
  if [[ "${count}" == "0" ]]; then
    output="string1"
  else
    output="string2"
  fi
  echo "\$output"
  exit
ENDSSH
```

We use `\$output` so that it is expanded on remote host not locally.

Comment: Also note that value of `$count` is passed from current shell to remote shell

Answer (score 2):

It is [better not to use *stdin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797019/45375) (such as by using here-docs) to pass commands to `ssh`.

If you use a *command-line argument* to pass your shell commands instead, you can better separate what is expanded locally and what will be executed remotely:

```
# Use a *literal* here-doc to read the script into a *variable*.
# Note how the script references parameter $1 instead of
# local variable $count.
read -d '' -r script <<'EOF'
  [[ $1 == '0' ]] && output='zero' || output='nonzero'
  echo "$output"
EOF

# The variable whose value to pass as a parameter.
# With value 0, the script will echo 'zero', otherwise 'nonzero'.
count=0

# Use `set -- '$<local-var>'...;` to pass the local variables as
# positional parameters, followed by the script code.
ssh localhost "set -- '$count'; $script"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the variables as @anubhava said, or, if you get too much variables for the escaping, you can do it in two steps:

```
# prepare the part which should not be expanded
# note the quoted 'EOF'
read -r -d '' commands <<'EOF'
if [[ "$count" == "0" ]]; then
    echo "$count - $HOME"
else
    echo "$count - $PATH"
fi
EOF

localcount=1
#use the unquoted ENDSSH
ssh me@nox.local <<ENDSSH
count=$localcount # count=1
#here will be inserted the above prepared commands
$commands 
ENDSSH
```

will print something like:

```
1 - /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```