# Remove verbosity from sudo with pseudo-terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sudo

If I run the following script on some hosts:

```
ssh -t myhost /usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash <<'HERE_DOCUMENT'
whoami
uptime
exit
HERE_DOCUMENT
```

I get the following output:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

as sudo settings have `requiretty` enabled. I don't want to change that setting.

So my fix from [existing StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122115/160984) is to add -tt option to ssh.

```
ssh -tt myhost /usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash <<'HERE_DOCUMENT'
whoami
uptime
exit
HERE_DOCUMENT
```

But that creates another problem, the output becomes too verbose:

```
[root@myhost ec2-user]# whoami
root
[root@myhost ec2-user]# uptime
 03:44:29 up 2 days,  3:26,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
[root@myhost ec2-user]# exit
exit
Connection to myhost closed.
```

What is the best way to remove prompts and command echoing?
The commands are just examples, and I do need sudo access to run privileged commands.

Comment: Since you have `sudo` access, perhaps you could add your public key to `~root/.ssh/authorized keys`, then do `ssh root@myhost /bin/bash < HERE_DOCUMENT [...]`.  In other words, just log in as root via ssh, instead of running `sudo` once you get there.

Comment: You should post it as an answer. This could help others. In my case I want to minimize any changes to remote system. Root is not always allowed to ssh directly to host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start an interactive shell on the tty if you don't want an interactive shell session. Just start a shell that runs your command noninteractively:

```
ssh -tt host "sudo bash -c '
  whoami
  uptime
  '"
```