# Executing SSH with ShellJs

Tags: node.js, ssh, shelljs

I have been using shelljs to execute certain set of commands. So i tried to connect to a remote ubuntu server over ssh via shelljs.
This is my nodejs file.

```
var shelljs = require('shelljs');
shelljs.exec('ssh -i [path/to/pem/file] ubuntu@[taregt_ip]');
```

But i get this error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

So how to solve this issue or is there any other utility to connect to ssh with one single command.

EDIT: the link you guys are posting for me to refer in not the duplicate of my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH doesn't always allocate a pseudo-terminal.  That is explained in this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal).  You should add the `-tt` flag to force this.

That said, I wouldn't use `shelljs` to do ssh.  As you are just executing a local binary, this solution a) is not portable and b) will not know how to parse errors or deal with unexpected output. I have used [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#start-an-interactive-shell-session) in the past for similar projects, as it has an interactive SSH option, which makes it easy to create streams (STDOUT and STDIN) from an SSH connection.

Comment: I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal), but didn't find it useful.
`ssh2` seemed to the right choice but it throws this error.
`Timed out while waiting for handshake`

Comment: @Satnam run it in verbose mode.  I would imagine there is a problem with your SSL config, which is why both are giving you issues.