# entering a double-hop machine using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to access machine C from my local machine (A). I have ssh-keys with B, which happens to have ssh-keys with C, so I'm trying to:

```
ssh -X user_B@ip_B "ssh -X user_C@ip_C"
```

but this doesn't connect (gave "Connection to ... closed." after about a minute), and also gives back:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

The error message is solved by [adding -tt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7114990/3512538) but I'm still stuck with no conection.

This works if I do the ssh in two steps, i.e. first, connect to B, and then, once I'm in B's terminal, connect to C...

Tried also [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/311457/768410). Didn't work.

Comment: When you say you did `-tt`, was that for C? Should probably be `ssh -t B "ssh C". What do you get with `-v` ?

Comment: You probably should have stayed on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). "Double hop" machines are usually (often?) called "jump boxes". Also see questions like [SSH into remote host using jump box](https://serverfault.com/q/909026/145545) on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Jump boxes usually refer to a machine in the DMZ. They are not limited to SSH. They show up in Windows networks with the RDP protocol, too.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
ssh -t user_B@ip_B "ssh -t user_C@ip_C"
```

Comment: well, it doesn't for me

Comment: Ok try to provide debug information. add `-vvvv` for both ssh and share them via pastebin.

Comment: I added my ssh key to machine C and now it is working. Not sure if the key was the fix (I think not, but now the problem does not reproduce)

Comment: Ah, quite possible, I did in fact have my local ssh key installed on both servers I tested this with.