# select interactive menu option by bash shell

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a shell that makes choices on an interactive menu.
In the manual version I execute:

```
- ssh connection to the host
- I select the menu item 4 (console start)
- I run the "show vpn connection" command (it returns a number)
- I type "exit" to close the console
- I select the menu item 0 (exit)
```

I tried to create a shell of this type:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=172.19.0.9
USER="admin"
PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxx"
COMMAND="show vpn connection status"
SSH="/usr/bin/ssh"
$SSH -tt $USER@$HOST << EOF
4
$COMMAND
exit
0
EOF
```

It asks me for the password but no output is returned to me.
I only get the message "Connection to $HOST closed."
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the software that produces the interactive menu on the remote host?

Comment: Hi, is a Sophos XG Firewall console

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help me. But it's certainly worth [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58322790/edit) to add that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using "expect".
Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh <HOST IP> -l admin
expect "password:"
send "<Admin Password>\r"
expect "Select Menu Number \[0-7\]:"
send "7\r"
expect "Shutdown(S/s) or Reboot(R/r) Device  (S/s/R/r):  No (Enter) >"
send "r\r"
expect eof
exit
```

Thank you all.
AlAn

Answer (score 0):

So I think this can help you:

Put all of your commands in `file`, then run

`cat file | sshpass -p $yourpassword ssh -T IP_address`

this will read the file and pass it as STDIN for the ssh command. `sshpass` is to go past the login, and `ssh -T` disables pseudo-tty allocation ([Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal))

Comment: Hi @Sami and thank,
I was already trying this kind of solution, but another problem is generated:
**stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device**
Do you have any idea?
Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry I have no idea why it does that, it worked fine when i tested that on my computer. Do you own the distant host ?