# Pulling a Bitbucket Repo directly is successful. Fails when done via a pipeline

Tags: shell, ssh, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I'm attempting to deploy from a bitbucket pipeling to a Digital Ocean droplet.

When going via the pipeline this is unsucessful resulting in a `permission denied (publickey)` error.

However, when attempting to run the exact same file from the shell on the server the git pull is successful.

I can't figure out why this might fail via one method and not the other considering it's the same file that is attempting to pull from bitbucket.

#### Bitbucket Pipeline Fail

[image]

#### Pull.sh on the Digital Ocean Droplet

```
# Change to the git directory
printf "${Red}=== Repo Pull ===${Color_Off}\n"
printf "${Red}Changing Directory to 'eg-api'\n"
cd eg-api

#Pull From Repo
printf "${Red}Attempting pull from repo${Color_Off}\n"
git pull origin master
printf "${Red}Repo: Local Copy Updated${Color_Off}\n"

#Change Directory
cd refgator-api

# Starts the application
python3 refgator-api.py
```

#### Successful repo Pull when executing directly on the droplet.

```
=== Repo Pull ===
Changing Directory to 'eg-api'
Attempting pull from repo
From bitbucket.org:[myusername]/[myrepo]
 * branch              master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
Repo: Local Copy Updated
```

#### With -vvv enabled

Using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git pull git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myrepo.git` instead of `git pull origin master` in pull.sh

The below is output when attempting the deployment from the Bitbucket Pipeline:

```
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzX...
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

And the below is the output provided when running th eexact same file from Digital Ocean.

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ebh... agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ebh... agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:ebh...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa SHA256:ebh...
debug3: send packet: type 50
```

so it's obvious that the key is accepted via one method but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was addressed by modifying the deploy.sh script held on bitbucket to include the `ssh -tt` argument.

```
 default:
       - step:
           script:
-              - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
+              - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh -tt root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
               - echo "Deploy step finished"
```

Helped out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal) answer