# Trying to execute a shell script on the Linux server via the gitlab-runner

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci

I have been trying to set up a CI pipeline in GitLab which will execute `auto_update_test.sh` file whenever a feature branch gets merged with the main branch. I have installed `gitlab-runner` on my Linux server and registered it using the project runner.

The GitLab repo on my server is under `/opt/splunktest`. The content of `auto_update_test.sh` are as below:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
Path to your Splunk app directory
APP_DIR="/opt/splunktest"
#Git pull in the dev branch
cd "$APP_DIR" || exit
cd /opt/splunktest
git pull origin main
```

below are the content of .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - ./auto_update_test.sh
only:
 - main
```

I want `auto_update_test.sh` to be executed on my server when I merge a feature branch, let's say "dev" branch, to the main branch in GitLab.

When I am pushing a text change on the `splunktext.txt` from dev branch and merging the dev to main then it says "No such file or directory" error:

[gitlab build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1laqy.png)

I have tried checking out all the permission. The repo is set up as a splunk user and have also added gitlab-runner user to the splunk group.

```
$ getent group splunk
splunk:x:2003:gitlab-runner
```

I have added all the permission, auto_update_test.sh has the executable permission.

Restarted the splunk and the gitlab-runner user

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking:

[GitLab CI/CD Pipeline: Run Script via SSH to remote server](https://karol-filipczuk.medium.com/gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-run-script-via-ssh-to-remote-server-9594f326bc2f)

[Better way for multiline ssh command](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/better-way-for-multiline-ssh-command/23420)

**TL;DR**

1. Create SSH keys.
   You'll get 2 keys: one **private-key** (ex: id_ed25519) and one **public-key** (ex: id_ed25519.pub)
2. Add the **private-key** as a **GitLab Variable**:
   Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables -> Expand -> Add Variable
   (GitLab’s variable is a key-value pair. Name the **key** SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and paste your **private-key** in the **value** field. Then Click Add Variable.)
3. Add one more Gitlab variable: **DServerIP** as the IP address of the remote server (in your case, the server hosting the gitLab-runner)
4. Add the **public-key** to the remote server under the **.ssh** folder (it should be /home/username/.ssh or /root/.ssh)
5. Paste the **public-key** into **authorized_keys** file (it should be /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys or /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, but if you don’t have authorized_keys file, create it.)
6. use the following script in your .gitlab-ci file

```js
image: alpine:latest

stages:
  - Execute_script_on_remote_host

update:
  stage: Execute_script_on_remote_host
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan $DServerIP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - scp  ./auto_update_test.sh root@$DServerIP:/opt/splunktest
    - |
      ssh  -tt root@$DServerURL /bin/bash -s << EOT
      cd /opt/splunktest
      chmod +x auto_update_test.sh
      bash auto_update_test.sh
      exit
      EOT
```

Notes:

- make sure that the file **auto_update_test.sh** is in the same directory as .gitlab-ci.yml (or just change its path in the script)
- you can put all your commands into a shell script (ex: remote_update.sh) in your project and change the SSH command:

remote_update.sh:

```js
cd /opt/splunktest
chmod +x auto_update_test.sh
bash auto_update_test.sh
exit
```

SSH command in the script:

```js
script:
    - scp  ./auto_update_test.sh root@$DServerIP:/opt/splunktest
    - ssh  -tt root@$DServerIP "/bin/bash -s" <remote_update.sh
```

- you even can connect via ssh and execute the commands of the auto_update_test.sh file without the need to copying it to the remote server.

SSH command in the script:

```js
script:
    - ssh  -tt root@$DServerIP "/bin/bash -s" <auto_update_test.sh
```

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/649186/how-can-i-get-the-scp-command-to-overwrite-the-destination-folder
- [Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Your runner is using the [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html). When you run jobs with this runner, it creates new docker containers for each job. The container has its own filesystem separate from your 'baremetal' host where the runner is installed.

Therefore you have two problems:

1. you won't find `/opt/splunk` in your container filesystem (the immediate cuase of your error)
2. Running the script inside your job container *may* not have the effect you're expecting it to have on the host system, since it's running inside a container.

If you only need to update files on the host in the `/opt/splunk` directory, you can configure your runner to mount this directory from the host into your job containers, so that `/opt/splunk` from the host will be available in `/opt/splunk` in the job containers and changes within that directory will persist on the host.

In your runner's `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`, you can add this `volumes` key:

```ini
# ...
[runners.docker]
  # ...
  volumes = ["/opt/splunk"]
```

Then restart your runner.

You could also consider using a [*shell* executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) instead, which would run jobs (and commands therein) directly on the same host and filesystem(s) where the runner is installed.

Comment: t20$ ./auto_update_test.sh
21./auto_update_test.sh: line 8: cd: /opt/splunktest: No such file or directory
22Switched to a new branch 'main'
23branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
24From https://gitlab.com/bhp-cloudfactory/devops-hr-learning-and-business-apps/splunktest
25 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
26Already up to date.
27Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
28Job succeeded
I have added the volumes in toml config file but still it is unable to find the path?
21./auto_update_test.sh: line 8: cd: /opt/splunktest: No such file or directory

Comment: @AmitSuman make sure your runner user has permission to the directory and restart the runner.