# Making an alias for SSH MySQL login using ENDSSH heredoc

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, alias, heredoc

I want to make an alias that is kept in my bashrc file to log into a remote MySQL db via SSH. 
Assume that I can't add/alter any files on the remote machine that I'm SSHing into. Here's the relevant code.

```
function ssh_mysql {
  echo "SSHing to $server"
  ssh -t -t $suser@$server <<ENDSSH
    eval "mysql -h "$host" -u $user -p $pass $db"
ENDSSH
}
alias wt_mysql=ssh_mysql
```

The Problem: Entering 'wt_mysql' into the terminal as an alias SSHs and logs into MySQL fine.. but when trying to enter any command/query/etc at the MySQL prompt, none of what I've submitted is executed/run. Including the 'exit' command. I have to ctrl C to get back to my local terminal. although its a bit out of my understanding I *believe* the problem is related to this topic,  [Terminating SSH session executed by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085429/terminating-ssh-session-executed-by-bash-script)

How can I make sure that mysql and any subsequent commands are executed remotely?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you define `function ssh_mysql` and then `alias wt_mysql=ssh_mysql` instead of defining only `function wt_mysql`? I assume in my answer that you get the same problem running `ssh_mysql` as you do running `wt_mysql`, but if that is the case then why did you tell us about the alias? In general you should make it easy for people to help you by simplifying your question as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was over thinking things.. I always intended this to be an alias so that it'd appear in the stdout with an alias command. My problem was that I had this funky password to contend with that had a | character. Adding my particular solution to the comments of your solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using `eval` (or why you're passing the `-t` switch twice).

I would expect this ssh command to do what you want:

```
ssh -t $suser@$server "mysql -h '$host' -u $user -p $pass $db"
```

Comment: I think `-t` is needed at least once (to run an interactive program over `ssh`); twice should be harmless.

Comment: @chepner Yes, `-t` is needed to allocate a terminal... I was confused about what the second `-t` was supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks again @dave4420 Here's what worked in my particular case of making an ssh+mysql alias:  `function ssh_mysql(){
ssh -t $suser@$server "mysql -h "$host" -u "$user" --password='"$pass"' "$db""
}
alias wt_mysql=ssh_mysql`