# Terminating SSH GNU Screen session executed by bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run a bash script on my local machine that starts a long-running process in screen in SSH and exit.

Screen and the long-running process runs fine.

But on my host machine, the script hangs which has to be killed manually.

```sh
  ssh -tt $SSH_URL <<EOT
  screen -d -r my_session
  # some commands or just do nothing
  screen -d
  EOT
```

This hags indefinitely.

PS: Terminating SSH session (non screen) is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085429/terminating-ssh-session-executed-by-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to run a bash script on my local machine that starts a long-running process in screen in SSH and exit.

Run the script with:

```sh
./somescript.sh &
```

[Here's explained why](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/).