# Why does ssh + nohup not work with network-related processes?

Tags: git, unix, ssh, wget, nohup

I have have been trying to use ssh for triggering some installation scripts over the network. Initially those scripts were using `git clone` but I kept getting error code `141` (which seems to be `SIGPIPE` according to git [mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/89516/match=141)). Trying to replace git with wget shows the same issue, i.e.:

```
ssh user@server 'nohup wget http://google.ch &' // produce no result on the server
ssh user@server // then on the server
nohup wget http://google.ch & // works
```

Already tried with different servers (debian/ubuntu/vm/native). Using apt this way works though.
Any idea on the reasons and suggested solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Several responses here may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185717/bash-spawn-subshell-for-ssh-and-continue-with-program-flow/5199505#5199505 .. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in similar situations, the pointer of @**shellter** was a good read (thanks !). One solution is to use `-t -t` as ssh flags and be careful not to include the background toggle in the command, i.e.:

```
ssh -t -t user@server 'nohup command' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```